# range.moveStart() function in IE11 non compatible mode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have a text box(numeric) in which numbers can entered or deleted.
On pressing the backspace key a value from a certain position is be deleted and a javascript function as below is called.

```js
function getCaretPosition(textObject)
{
 var position = 0;
 if(textObject.createTextRange)
 {
  
  var range="";
  if (window.getSelection)
  {
   range = window.getSelection();
  }
  if (document.getSelection)
  {
  range = document.getSelection();
  }
  if(range=="")
  {
   if (document.selection)
   {
   range = document.selection.createRange().duplicate();
   }
  }
  
  //range = document.selection.createRange().duplicate();
  range.moveStart('textedit', -1);
  position = range.text.length;
 }
 else if(textObject.setSelectionRange)
  position = textObject.selectionEnd;
 return position;
}
```

When i run the application in IE11 non compatible mode and use the backspace key on the text field, a javascript error occurs as below:

**"Object doesn't support property or method 'moveStart'"**

I'm guessing that moveStart method is not supported in IE11.
Can someone please suggest on how to overcome this issue?
This seems to be working fine in IE11 compatible mode though.

Comment: Any luck on this? I'm having the same issue